# vscode doesn't catch flake8 output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

I currently work on a project which uses `flake8` as a python linter. Previously I was using `pylint` for all my projects. So I work in Visual Studio Code, I also use `black` as code formatter.

So now everything works, except for `flake8`. Code gets formatted by black, but I don't see any problems under `Problems` tab:

[image]

, even if I can see them under `Output` (so flake8 actually gets called, but its errors are not piped to vs code):

```sh
##########Linting Output - flake8##########
0,1,I,I002:no configuration found (.isort.cfg or [isort] in configs)
1,1,C,C101:Coding magic comment not found
1,1,D,D100:Missing docstring in public module
5,21,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
5,46,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
7,1,W,WPS111:Found too short name: a
7,5,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
10,12,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
11,1,D,D103:Missing docstring in public function
12,21,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
12,31,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
15,16,Q,Q000:Remove bad quotes
16,1,S,S201:A Flask app appears to be run with debug=True, which exposes the Werkzeug debugger and allows the execution of arbitrary code.
```

Those are my python/flake related options in vs code:

```
// Python settings
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "-l",
    "79"
],
"python.jediEnabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
```

And, of course, I have `flake8` installed (both globally and in `pipenv`).

So, is there a way to solve this? I am asking here, cuz flake GH repo is just a mirror and I cannot create an `Issue` there.

@Edit

When I run the linting via `Ctrl+Shift+P->Python: Run linting`, the output gets printed to the `Output` tab like before, but I get the popup:

[image]

Comment: Please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a [known reported issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7349). There is also a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/8476) submitted to fix this. At the time of writing, this fix is not yet included in a release.